# Datepicker with trigger button and 100% width

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is any simple way to create datepicker (jqueryUI) with button trigger & 100% width? Now it do not handle this situation:

http://jsbin.com/uriwaw/1/edit

Of course I can set width in pixels, but it is not my target.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://jsbin.com/uriwaw/9)?

You need to set  `buttonImageOnly` to `false` and add your style